# Thank you $name is displaying as it is not showing the persons name

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php
        $Email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Number= $_POST['Number'];
        $Subject= $_POST['Subject'];
        $Message= $_POST['Message'];
        $formcontent="
                  Name: $Name \n
                  Email: $Email \n
                  Number: $Number \n
                  Subject: $Subject\n
                  Message: $Message";
        $recipient = "info@domain.com";
        $mailheader = "From: $Name \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $Subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
        echo "<h4 align= center><b>Thank You $Name!</b></h4>";
     ?>
```

For this PHP code the result displaying as Thank You $Name!";?> in offline not in serverside. Why it is not showing the person name?

Comment: This should not show any issue. Check what value is coming for `$_POST['Name']`, before printing the last line.

Comment: $_POST['Name'] is taking the exact name of the person but not displaying in result

Answer (score 2):

Try this :\

```
  echo "<h4 align= center><b>Thank You ".$Name."!</b></h4>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
echo "<h4 align= center><b>Thank You '".$Name."'!</b></h4>";
```

Comment: Thank You " '.$Name.' "!"; ?> is displaying in my contact form

Comment: Thats what I mean to say @manadh whats the difference answers had yours consist extra inverted commas nothing else

Comment: I have not hosted this code, If i host it, will it work properly  showing like Thank You San.